# Tableau - YTD, MTD as columns in text table

Tags: tableau-api

[image]

I'm trying to find a way to create a table like the one above, but instead of having columns of months I would like to have columns of MTD, QTD, YTD for all selected measure values. I created calculated fields on the [Date] field but when I try to use that it still splits the data in to separate columns of months and quarters... I'm using two data sources and they are linked on the [Date] field. If I try to put two of my calculated fields in the columns bar it just combines them like 'MTD/YTD'. How can I get them to display as separate columns?
I know this is strange because there will be overlapping data (everything in the MTD will also be in the QTD and the YTD).

Answer (score 1):

I found a way to do this. I created a calculated field on the date field and assigned 'MTD' to all records from the last month. Then I assigned 'QTD' to all records from the start of the quarter to the day before the start date of the 'MTD' records. Then I assigned 'YTD' to all records from the start of the year to the day before the start of the 'QTD' records. (this way there are no overlapping records).
After that I just did a quick table calc to make each of them a 'running total' table (across). [image]

I created parameters for the dates so the can easily be updated.